# Draw a Spectograph for FFT iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, fft, spectrogram

I am developing a code to display Spectrograph on iOS devices.I have the FFT data with me how to I plot the Spectograph with the FFT data.

Answer (score 0):

You  can refer [MIM-Library](https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library), it may help you, it have some good charts in each category.

MIM-Library's Wall chart may fulfill your need.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some details and information about the link instead of just posting it? Stack Overflow aims to be an archive of knowledge, and if that link ever goes dead for whatever reason then this answer becomes useless.

Comment: @Jasarien Thank you, I came for doing same here, You did it well